# Why my osx lion can't setup soptlight?

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long should Lion take to set up Spotlight?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19776/how-long-should-lion-take-to-set-up-spotlight)

My mac osx from snow leopard 10.6.8 update to Lion,all os setup is all right,but it lookslike can't setpu soptlight ,it stand for the loading process for a long time.(more than 3 hours)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried repairing the disk & its permissions? This usually resets spotlight.